# magento2: how to put widget (slider) in header?

Tags: magento2, header, widgets, slider

could anyone advise me how to put widget (slider) in header just next to logo? (as on screenshot below)?
Widget is ready and prepared by TemplateMonster extension, i just want to move it upstairs, like on screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the layout configurations for the extension and extend them in your theme in order to `<move>` the element after the logo in the header.

Check the layout configurations for the header to get the elements name first and then do the rest. This documentation can help you get into XML configs for Magento 2: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html